# Outlook 2010 briefly freezes when pressing send. Most users experiencing this

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

Many of our users are suddenly experiencing Outlook "freezing" briefly after pressing send.  This also occurs when a user types in a name not in the address book and clicks "Check Names"

I've checked resources on our cas array and our two dag servers, everything appears fine.  Any assistance?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the event logs show nothing I would use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) on a client (clinets) and see if there is a file the app is searching for or another local issue.  The Process Monitor tool should assist in finding a long timeout at a specific time and you can then possibly identify the issue if a client side issue